# Automatically escape special characters

Tags: jobname

I have a document where I would like to put the jobname into the footer with the `\jobname` macro. However, if my main file has underscores in its file name, the jobname cannot be printed properly due to the underscore. How can I tell LaTeX to automatically escape any special characters in the jobname?

Comment: The underscores in `\jobname` are not math subscript characters and should not give an error. If you are getting errors please show code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I think "cannot be printed properly" means the strange overdots instead of the underscores. `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` might be enough.

Comment: @campa probably. But should have that anyway:-)

Comment: I tend to use `\path` from the `url` package for this, in this case try `\expandafter\path\expandafter{\jobname}`

Comment: unfortunately, the underscores are replaced with inverted commas. I think this is because the underscore in normal LaTeX mode means a special thing.See http://imgur.com/a/YKwLU - this is the result if my main file is called 'test_with_underscores.tex'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tend to use `\path` from the `url` package, though you need to expand `\jobname` first

```
\expandafter\path\expandafter{\jobname}
```

Controlling the font of `\path` (it is `tt` by default) can be done by making a custom `\path` command, see the source of `url.sty`

Comment: Controlong????????

Comment: Controlling? Or is controling American usage? (I don't want to change it if it is correct American.)

Comment: @cfr I'm not American, change whatever you want