# `\jobname` doesn't handle underscores properly

Tags: jobname

In [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/351863/automatically-escape-special-characters), @DavidCarlisle asked for an example showing that `\jobname` doesn't handle underscores properly.    Here's an example

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\jobname \\
\today
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

If you call this file `This_is_an_example.tex` you'll see that the underscores are replaced by raised dots.   Could you provide a fix for this?  In the same thread people talked about fixes but it would be wonderful if somebody could provide an MWE that actually fixes the problem.

Comment: Doesn't `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` in the preamble fix the issue?

Comment: @Troy  That is a good solution.  Why don't you offer that as your answer.

Comment: But the best solution (IMHO, of course) and not only in TeX  is not use underscores or spaces in filenames. WikiWords  are more readables and otherwise hyphens always work, even in the oldest MSDOS.

Comment: Related/duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/351863/4427

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're using pdflatex, you should pass `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` in the preamble, because the underscore `_` character doesn't exist in the default OT1 (old text) encoding.

Doing so yields the expected result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much!   I'm puzzled about the underscore thing:   `_` is handled literally by the `\jobname` call, but if you put `code_folding` in the body of the text it throws the expected error.   That seems inconsistent.

Comment: @LeoSimon This "inconsistency" is because how TeX handles catcodes here. A call of `\jobname` returns all characters of the file name with fixed catcode 12 "other character" (or 10 for spaces). TeX normally handles these characters by just adding them to the output, which gives wrong results if the corresponding glyph in the font table is different from the glyph you expect at that position. OTOH, if a literal `_` occurs in the text, the catcode hasn't been assigned yet and thus is given the default one (in this case 8 "subscript") as soon as TeX "sees" the character in the input stream.